# Convert string[] to int

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, int

I have an array of integers in string form.

```
string [] TriangleSideLengths
```

In this array there is going to be 3 int values which represent side length of a triangle. Is there a way from which I can extract individual all 3 values from my array TriangleSideLengths into three int objects like int intSideLengthOne,intSideLengthTwo and intSideLengthThree.

I want to be able to test if these three values actually form a valid triangle?

For instance, entering lengths 10, 10, 100000 wouldn't make it a valid isosceles triangle.

I wanna be able to do this check with the three values stored in my array TriangleSideLengths.

```
a + b > c
a + c > b
b + c > a
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LINQ to parse the numbers from the string, like this:

```
var threeSides = TriangleSideLengths.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/XSmy4e).

To do the check, sort the numbers in ascending order, then check that the sum of the first two is strictly greater than the third one:

```
Array.Sort(threeSides);
if (threeSides[0]+threeSides[1] > threeSides[2]) {
    ...
}
```

Note that it is not a sufficient condition for the numbers to define a triangle: you must also check that the numbers are strictly positive.

Comment: Hi @dasblinkenlight , I already have a check for negative numbers,alphabets and special characters. Let me give this approach a whirl and I will report back here.! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: This is awesome and it works like a charm! Thanks a lot this was such a great help for me :)))) Good night :) @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @dashblinkenlight: this doesn't work without the split.  Your edit is probably in response to the fact that he said he has an array of three strings, but if so you should really fix the name of your variable "strSides" is gong to be confusing.  sideStrings works as does the OP's TriangleSideLengths.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string [] TriangleSideLengths = new string[3];
int[] lengths = new int[3];
for(int i = 0; i<=2;i++)
{
 lengths[i]=Convert.ToInt32(TriangleSideLengths[i]);
}
if(lengths[0]+lengths[1]>lengths[2])
   //go crazy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] TriangleSideLengths = { "10", "20", "300"};

int[] sides = new int[TriangleSideLengths.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < TriangleSideLengths.Length; i++)    
{       
    sides[i] = int.Parse(TriangleSideLengths[i]);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] sides = new int[TriangleSideLengths.Length];
int counter=0;
foreach(var str in TriangleSideLengths)
{
   int.TryParse(str, out sides[counter++]);
}
if(sides[0] + sides[1] > sides[2]){...}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int toInt(string text)
{
    int tonumber = int.Parse(text);
    return tonumber;
}
```

Comment: How does usage of this function differ from the built in int.Parse?